# Proposal for Mage Stackday 2

Tags: discussion

**UPDATE:** Thanks for everyone for responding in positive way and for voting and special thanks for Sander and Anna lets make `#MageStackDay` a big success.

I feel it's time to start `Mage Stackday2` as the `answered % is 72(reduced 1% recently)` I feel we all should join hands and minds too to increase this percentage.We have `2370` [unanswered](https://magento.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) questions it's not an hard task if we unite to solve this.So please think about this and lets schedule a day or two for doing this job.

Comment: We should summon Anna Völkl and Sander Mangel on this. They did a great job organizing the last one. By the way I think we should make this event recurring. (once every 2 months maybe).

Comment: Already on it ;) Will do a poll some time soon but for now I would say somewhere in February?

Comment: @marius : ya i already told this on slack. we need to held #mageStackDay recursively

Comment: @sanderMangel : a poll would be nice

Comment: i am agree with @Marius

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your wish is your command... Please go and vote for a new MageStackDay date!
http://magestackday.com/#2015edition